# Populate Datagridview price chart

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, datagridview

I want to populate my **DataGridView** (`dgvMain`) with Bitcoin price I get using webrequest API.

The Price example response from request: `36.560` should be populated in the `row1` and 4th column (`column(3)`)

My Code:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    getPriceBTC()
    InitializeDataGridView()

End Sub

 Private Sub InitializeDataGridView()

    ' Set the column header style.
    Dim columnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()

    'columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
    columnHeaderStyle.Font = New Font("arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    dgvMain.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle

    ' Set the column header names.
    dgvMain.ColumnCount = 11

    dgvMain.Columns(0).Name = "#"
    dgvMain.Columns(0).Width = 50
    dgvMain.Columns(1).Name = "ID"
    dgvMain.Columns(2).Name = "Coin"
    dgvMain.Columns(3).Name = "Price (EUR)"
    dgvMain.Columns(4).Name = "Last 1h"
    dgvMain.Columns(5).Name = "Last 24h"
    dgvMain.Columns(6).Name = "Last 7d"
    dgvMain.Columns(7).Name = "24h Volume"
    dgvMain.Columns(8).Name = "M. Capital"
    dgvMain.Columns(9).Name = "If Higher"
    dgvMain.Columns(10).Name = "If Lower"

    ' Populate the rows.
    Dim row1() As String = {"", "BTC", "BitCoin", "", "", " ", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row2() As String = {"", "ETH", "Ethereum", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row3() As String = {"", "ADA", "Cardano", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row4() As String = {"", "GLMR", "Moonbeam", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row5() As String = {"", "ELON", "Dogelon Mars", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row6() As String = {"", "MBOX", "Mobox", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row7() As String = {"", "BLOK", "Bloktopia", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row8() As String = {"", "STARL", "Starlink", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row9() As String = {"", "OOKI", "Ooki Protocol", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row10() As String = {"", "Floki", "Floki Inu", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row11() As String = {"", "EGC", "EverGrow Coin", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row12() As String = {"", "SQUID", "Squid Game", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row13() As String = {"", "HOT", "Holo", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row14() As String = {"", "ATLAS", "Star Atlas", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row15() As String = {"", "ZODI", "Zodium", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row16() As String = {"", "VML", "Meta Land", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
    Dim row17() As String = {"", "SNN", "SeChain", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}


    Dim rows() As Object = {row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10, row11, row12, row13, row14, row15, row16, row17}

    Dim rowArray As String()
    For Each rowArray In rows
        dgvMain.Rows.Add(rowArray)
    Next rowArray

    Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    dgvMain.Columns.Add(chk)
    chk.HeaderText = "Enable"
    chk.Name = "chk"
    chk.Width = 70
End Sub

Public Sub getPriceBTC()
Try
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    'Dim _price As String = txtCryptoPrice.Text

    Dim _url As String = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=EUR"
    Dim _req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_url)
    _req.Proxy = Nothing
    _req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.81 Safari/537.36"

    Dim _resp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = _req.GetResponse
    Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(_resp.GetResponseStream())
    Dim API_source As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd
    Dim _Fprice = API_source.ToLower.ToString
    Dim _priceF = _Fprice.Substring(7)
    Dim jsonprice As String = _priceF.Replace("}", "")
  Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Nothing
        For Each item As DataGridViewRow In dgvMain.Rows
            row = item
            row.Cells(3).Value = jsonprice
        Next
    _runningThreads.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread)
Catch ex As Exception

End Try

End Sub
```

> I added piece of CODE after I edited but it shows now in all CELLS
> the btc price so how DO I add it only to the first row?
> row.Cells(3).Value = jsonprice

Comment: Anyone could help pls ?

Answer (score 1):

heheheh I google it :p

```
 dgvMain.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = jsonprice
```

yeees!

Comment: Even though YOU understand the answer...How would anyone else?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani hahah yeah but the issue now I have is when data populate and timer will refresh every 1sec then IF I sort the grid view by name or other it will populate in the same cell and if the name is different it will mich mach the prices for each currency this is so stressfull

Comment: I don't really understand your problem and the solution lacks clarity for the benefit of other people. That being said I recommend that you use column names instead of indexes. By default, a user can  move columns in a DataGridView control by drag & drop, so the column index can change. Column names are more intuitive and constant.

Comment: @Kate ok thanks and any source of I can check? I never deal with this columns and rows so if I sort and click the column up and down the price will get wrong place you know thank you for help

Comment: What I mean is, instead of doing `row.Cells(3).Value = jsonprice` you could simply write `row.Cells("Price (EUR)").Value = jsonprice` or whatever column name you used. This would be more intuitive and less error-prone, *especially if the column order changes*. Also, it is more common to bind a DGV to a datatable or dataset, rather than populate it like you are doing. Look up for examples, there is a lot that can be improved in the current code. I believe that using the Newtonsoft.Json library for example you could easily deserialize the JSON to a datatable-like structure.

Comment: @Kate i test and it work but it will now populate all cells not only the one for Bitcoin image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK4yF.png